# How do I determine if "WriteAllText" in Visual Basic has completed successfully?

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program in VB 2010, using the WriteAllText method inside a Try..Catch block.  I want to do a 'MessageBox.Show' to indicate to the user that the file was successfully saved (ONLY when it's successfully saved!)  Is there a way that the WriteAllText method tells me that it was successful that I can use in an If..Then statement?

Comment: You've got the wrong instincts about .NET.  It never tells you that a method succeeded, no point in telling you what you *expect* to happen.  It only tells you when a method failed.  With an exception.

Answer (score 5):

`File.WriteAllText` will raise exceptions on failure.  Provided you get to the line after your call, and not into a Catch block, then you succeeded.

```
Try
    File.WriteAllText(filename, contents)

    ' This will only happen on success
    MessageBox.Show("Success") 
Catch ex As Exception
    ' On failure, you'll be here
End Try
```